# Mockito capture argument on "recording" time and use it later on execution time

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following code which I want to test:

```
pojo.setStatus(Status.INITIAL);
pojo.setExecutionCounter(0);
//eventRepository is a mock
scheduleEvent(this.eventRepository.save(pojo).get());
```

In a unit test, I'd like to verify that

- the pojo has been modified accordingly
- The event which will be scheduled has status `INITIAL` and the counter is `0`
- save of the mock has been called

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do that, since I have to return the argument which I have to `capture`. Maybe it's getting more clear when I show the example of my unit test:

```
succeededEvent.setEventStatus(INITIAL);
succeededEvent.setExecutionCounter(0);

//Actually we want here to return the argument 
//which is captured by eventArgumentCaptor??       
when(this.eventRepository.save(this.eventArgumentCaptor.capture()))
.thenReturn(succededEvent);

this.processor.processEvent(initialEvent);

Mockito.verify(this.eventRepository, 
Mockito.times(1)).save(eventCaptureExecuteCaptor.capture());

final Event capturedEvent = eventCaptureExecuteCaptor.getValue();
//Counter and status should be reset
assertEquals(new Integer(0), capturedEvent.getExecutionCounter());
assertEquals(INITIAL, capturedEvent.getEventStatus());
verify(this.eventRepository, 
times(1)).save(eq(eventCaptureExecuteCaptor.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need to use captor while stubbing.
You use it, as designed, after the invocation of the SUT:

```
this.processor.processEvent(initialEvent);

Mockito.verify(this.eventRepository, 
Mockito.times(1)).save(eventCaptureExecuteCaptor.capture());
```

While stubbing, you can directly go for the concrete object that is expected:

```
when(this.eventRepository.save(succededEvent)
   .thenReturn(succededEvent);
```

or use a generic input if you do not have that object at hand on set-up:

```
when(this.eventRepository.save(anyClass(EventPojo.class))
  .thenReturn(succededEvent);
```

**Edit**:

You can also use the `thenAnswer` along with accepting any input class of Pojo type:

```
when(this.eventRepository.save(Mockito.any(EventPojo.class))
  .thenAnswer(new Answer<EventPojo>(){
       EventPojo pojo = invocation.getArgument(0);
       return pojo;
  }
);
```

as this is an anonymous implementation, you can catch the state of the passed pojo if you have the need.

Comment: This won't work. As already said, I modify the entity in the code. I want to verify that these modifications happen before saving it.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are there any other modifications that happen to the pojo after the repository.save method is called?

Comment: No, but before. Basically the `processEvent` method is changing states of the POJO. And I'd like to verify that this happened. On the other hand I need to return back the POJO **containing the changes** since I go on working with the POJO returned by the save method.

Comment: Ok, so the pojo is created inside the method right? I mean it is not passed to the method nor is it injected as an instance field?

Comment: No, the pojo is passed to the method as parameter. Like shown in the code example.

Comment: Understood. Try to check my update and see if it helps